# Text alignment in nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Why 360 is not vertically aligned with Angle ?

I changed `text width` but it's not better ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    BLS/.store in=\BLS,
    BLS=1.1*\baselineskip
    }

    \tikzset{%
        TDPnode/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt,
                        minimum height=\BLS,draw,text depth=1.5pt},
        TDPetq/.style={TDPnode,anchor=north east,
            minimum width=3em + 10pt,fill=gray!40},
        TDPcas/.style={TDPnode,anchor=west,minimum width=3em},
        TDPfle/.style={>=stealth,semithick}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[TDPetq] (B0) at (0,0) {Angle ()} ;
    \node[TDPcas,anchor=west] (B1) at (B0.east) {360} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You also need some `text height` in `TDPnode`.

Comment: As an alternative to Ignasi's answer, add a `\strut` to the the '360' node; this will insert a zero-width box to make it the same height as the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all nodes aligned by their baseline, all of them need to have same `text depth` and `text height`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    BLS/.store in=\BLS,
    BLS=1.1*\baselineskip
    }

    \tikzset{%
        TDPnode/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt,
                        minimum height=\BLS,draw, text depth=2pt, text height=8pt},
        TDPetq/.style={TDPnode,anchor=north east,
            minimum width=3em + 10pt,fill=gray!40},
        TDPcas/.style={TDPnode,anchor=west,minimum width=3em},
        TDPfle/.style={>=stealth,semithick}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[TDPetq] (B0) at (0,0) {Angle ()} ;
    \node[TDPcas,anchor=west] (B1) at (B0.east) {360} ;

    \draw[red] (B0.base)--(B1.base);
    \draw[blue] (B0.base-|B0.west)--(B0.base-|B1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]